# How to get attached files from an email, using Pentaho Kettle?

Tags: email, pentaho, jobs, kettle

I'm stuck in a great problem. My task is to download some emails from a server using the IMAP protocol. This is accomplished by using the "get mails (POP3 / IMAP)" job entry, which downloads the emails, but in binary format.

Files in binary format are `.mail` files containing sender, subject, body, and encoded attachment files. I need to obtain separate files, because I must realize some steps with these files as input.

I've seen that there are third-party libraries or utilities to decode the `.mail` file and get the attachment file list. However, I want to do this process without any additional utility (because this should require a shell step, depending on the SO).

Is there any way or trick to get the attachments using only Pentaho job entries or transformation steps?

I'm using the version 5.1 of Pentaho Kettle.

Comment: Are any of those libraries java? if so you can call them directly from PDI without having to shell out.

Answer (score 4):

I will explain the whole process so that anybody can get the advantage of it.

**1)** Add `START` and `Get mails (POP3/IMAP)` job entries, and create a hop between them. 

 **2)** Edit the Get mails entry to use your IMAP server (host name, port number, username, password, etc), and click Test Connection to verify settings. 

 **3)** In the Target folder, uncheck Save message content and check Get mail attachment and Different folder for attachment. Define a target folder for both the Target directory and Attachment files folder. 

 **4)** On the Settings tab, select the IMAP folder that you want to download from. Change other settings as desired. 

 **5)** Click OK, Save the Job, and Run the job.

Comment: I cant seem to find the "Get Mails" step - did that change? I am using the latest version of Data Integration.

Comment: No idea about latest version. This is 5.3 and 5.4

Comment: I am using v7.0, it looks like the only files are Input:"Email Messages Input" and Utility: "Mail"

Comment: I know this is a bit old. But I had the same problem about don't find "Get Mails" step. It's a "Job entry" not a "Transformation step" so you can find it inside the "Design" tab of a job.

Comment: It seems filter option is not working properly, do you have any idea on that ?