# cannot get email attachment in Pentaho kettle

Tags: pentaho, email-attachments, email, pdi

I'm trying to extract an email attachement in kettle (Pentaho PDI) using the 'Email messages input', I looked at other examples and they all follow this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935443/how-to-get-attached-files-from-an-email-using-pentaho-kettle)  ,here the input step is different 'get mails (POP3 / IMAP)' and one can specify what to do with the attachment. I'm using PDI 5.2 and I tried it in 5.3, and this second type of input 'pop3/imap' is not there.

Is there any other way how to get hold of the attachment? thank you for help

Comment: I also cannot find the step "Get Mails". I think it was removed. Did you find a solution here?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a Job. And you will find this step there.