# How to extract an email Attachment with Pentaho Data Integration?

Tags: email, pentaho, data-extraction, pdi, pentaho-spoon

let me start with what I want to accomplish:

I get 20 email with reports from clients daily, and I had to extract the .xls files attached for each one and do some simple transformations depending on who sent the file.

With Pentaho Data Integration, I setup some trasnformations, but need to have the files previously extracted on a folder.

Now I want PDI read the email account (they already had an email messages input) but as I can see it only read the data of the email and I haven't found the way to extract the attachments from certains emails and save them to a folder...

If anyone has a solution not including pentaho, please answer I'm not married with pentaho, just need to accomplish the task.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get attached files from an email, using Pentaho Kettle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935443/how-to-get-attached-files-from-an-email-using-pentaho-kettle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Email messages input` does not have the ability to save the attachments to a folder.

However the `Get mails (POP3/IMAP)` job step has the ability to save the attachments, so you would extract the attachments with a job, and then launch an transformation to process them.

Comment: I think this is just called "Mail" under the "Utility" directory now. Does that sound correct? Perhaps this changed in a recent version.

Comment: Do we any idea why filter option is not working with Get mails step ?